# how to add a webreference to.net 1.1 website

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services

I have a website running on .net 1.1, I need to call a webservice from it, however I can not add a valid webreference to it with visual studio 2008. I installed Visual Studio 2003, but I can not even open the website because there is no project file in it. (There is no open web site option)

I am not familiar with Visual Studio 2003 or .net 1.1 (it was already 2.0 + VS 2005 when I started programming), any help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Visual Studio 2003 has no web site feature. You must be looking at the deployed web site and not at the sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the web service reference in Visual Studio 2008 by clicking "Add Service Reference..." -> "Advanced..." -> "Add Web Reference..." in the Compatibility section.

Comment: compatibility section brings up until .net 2.0 as I see on Visual Studio not 1.1, am I missing something?

Comment: Possibly you are right. You can try to change the target to .NET 2.0 in Visual Studio 2008 and go back to 1.1 if you really need to. If I were you, I would migrate the web site to .NET 2.0.

Comment: upgrading project would be the best, but not an option in my case, the problem is I can put it to 2.0 in vs2008 but then the web ref I add is not valid because Microsoft changed the format and everything about making web reference from 1.1 to 2.0